# Check password strength using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to implement a password strength feature for my textbox in my asp.net website.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
<span id="password_strength"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckPasswordStrength(password) {
        var password_strength = document.getElementById("password_strength");

        //if textBox is empty
        if(password.length==0){
            password_strength.innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }

        //Regular Expressions
        var regex = new Array();
        regex.push("[A-Z]"); //For Uppercase Alphabet
        regex.push("[a-z]"); //For Lowercase Alphabet
        regex.push("[0-9]"); //For Numeric Digits
        regex.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); //For Special Characters

        var passed = 0;

        //Validation for each Regular Expression
        for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
            if(new RegExp (regex[i]).test(password){
                passed++;
            }
        }

        //Validation for Length of Password
        if(passed > 2 && password.length > 8){
            passed++;
        }

        //Display of Status
        var color = "";
        var passwordStrength = "";
        switch(passed){
            case 0:
            case 1:
                passwordStrength = "Password is Weak.";
                color = "Red";
                break;
            case 2:
                passwordStrength = "Password is Good.";
                color = "darkorange";
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
                passwordStrength = "Password is Strong.";
                color = "Green";
                break;
            case 5:
                passwordStrength = "Password is Very Strong.";
                color = "darkgreen";
                break;
        }
        password_strength.innerHTML = passwordStrength;
        password_strength.style.color = color;
    }
</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <center><asp:label runat="server" text="Password :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="False"></asp:label></center>
        <center><asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" onkeyup="CheckPasswordStrength(this.value)"></asp:TextBox></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this code online. I tried it on my website and it does not work.
I would really appreciate if somebody can help me with my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read over http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for assistance in asking the right types of questions. I'd suggest with this example above asking something specific. The way it's worded now sounds like you're asking us to do research and find issues in your code snippet that you didn't write, and solve it for you. You should be able to ask a specific question first.

Comment: I have no idea what "does not work" means. Describe exact behavior. What is it doing, which line of code does it deviate from what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `break` into `case 3` and `case 0`. Then set `default` after `case 5`.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

EDIT:

I updated your function

```
 function CheckPasswordStrength(password) {
  var password_strength = document.getElementById("password_strength");


    //if textBox is empty
    if(password.length==0){
        password_strength.innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }

    //Regular Expressions
    var regex = new Array();
    regex.push("[A-Z]"); //For Uppercase Alphabet
    regex.push("[a-z]"); //For Lowercase Alphabet
    regex.push("[0-9]"); //For Numeric Digits
    regex.push("[$@$!%*#?&]"); //For Special Characters

    var passed = 0;

    //Validation for each Regular Expression
    for (var i = 0; i < regex.length; i++) {
        if((new RegExp (regex[i])).test(password)){
            passed++;
        }
    }

    //Validation for Length of Password
    if(passed > 2 && password.length > 8){
        passed++;
    }

    //Display of Status
    var color = "";
    var passwordStrength = "";
    switch(passed){
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            passwordStrength = "Password is Weak.";
            color = "Red";
            break;
        case 2:
            passwordStrength = "Password is Good.";
            color = "darkorange";
            break;
        case 3:
                break;
        case 4:
            passwordStrength = "Password is Strong.";
            color = "Green";
            break;
        case 5:
            passwordStrength = "Password is Very Strong.";
            color = "darkgreen";
            break;
    }
    password_strength.innerHTML = passwordStrength;
    password_strength.style.color = color;
}
```

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/Lko29h8m/1/

Comment: How do i add in the default after case 5? :)

Comment: Thank You so much for all the help. The password strength function finally works on my asp.net website... :)